# Add correct century to dates with year provided as "Year without century", %y

Tags: r

I have an file with birthdays in `%d%b%y` format. Some eg.

```
# "01DEC71" "01AUG54" "01APR81" "01MAY81" "01SEP83" "01FEB59"
```

I tried to reformat the date as

```
o108$fmtbirth <- format(as.Date(o108$birth, "%d%b%y"), "%Y/%m/%d")
```

and this is the result

```
# "1971/12/01" "2054/08/01" "1981/04/01" "1981/05/01" "1983/09/01" "2059/02/01"
```

These are birthdays and I see 2054. From this [page](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strptime.html) I see that year values between 00 and 68 are coded as 20 for century. Is there a way to toggle this, in my case I want only 00 to 12 to be coded as 20.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**1) chron**. chron uses 30 by default so this will convert them converting first to Date (since chron can't read those sorts of dates) reformatting to character with two digit years into a format that chron can understand and finally back to Date.

```
library(chron)
xx <- c("01AUG11", "01AUG12", "01AUG13") # sample data
as.Date(chron(format(as.Date(xx, "%d%b%y"), "%m/%d/%y")))
```

That gives a cutoff of 30 but we can get a cutoff of 13 using chron's `chron.year.expand` option:

```
library(chron)
options(chron.year.expand = 
     function (y, cut.off = 12, century = c(1900, 2000), ...) {
        chron:::year.expand(y, cut.off = cut.off, century = century, ...)
     }
)
```

and then repeating the original conversion. For example assuming we had run this options statement already we would get the following with our `xx` :

```
> as.Date(chron(format(as.Date(xx, "%d%b%y"), "%m/%d/%y")))
[1] "2011-08-01" "2012-08-01" "1913-08-01"
```

**2) Date only**.  Here is an alternative that does not use chron.  You might want to replace `"2012-12-31"` with `Sys.Date()` if the idea is that otherwise future dates are really to be set 100 years back:

```
d <- as.Date(xx, "%d%b%y")
as.Date(ifelse(d > "2012-12-31", format(d, "19%y-%m-%d"), format(d)))
```

EDIT: added Date only solution.

Comment: +1 however a caveat to the Date only solution: the output is no longer a Date class, but a character, so arithmetic will require back-transforming the output. Oy vey.

Comment: It is of the form `as.Date(...)` so clearly it is of `Date` class.

Answer (score 14):

See response from [related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27718360/r-incorrect-value-of-date-function?lq=1):

```
format(as.Date("65-05-14", "%y-%m-%d"), "19%y-%m-%d")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
o108$fmtbirth <- format(as.Date(o108$birth, "%d%b%y"), "%Y/%m/%d")

o108$fmtbirth <- as.Date(ifelse(o108$fmtbirth > Sys.Date(), 
                                format(o108$fmtbirth, "19%y-%m-%d"),
                                format(o108$fmtbirth)))
```