# Convert two-digit years to four-digit years with correct century

Tags: r, date, lubridate

If a date vector has two-digit years, `mdy()` turns years between 00 and 68 into 21st Century years and years between 69 and 99 into 20th Century years. For example:

```
library(lubridate)    
mdy(c("1/2/54","1/2/68","1/2/69","1/2/99","1/2/04"))
```

gives the following output:

```
Multiple format matches with 5 successes: %m/%d/%y, %m/%d/%Y.
Using date format %m/%d/%y.
[1] "2054-01-02 UTC" "2068-01-02 UTC" "1969-01-02 UTC" "1999-01-02 UTC" "2004-01-02 UTC"
```

I can fix this after the fact by subtracting 100 from the incorrect dates to turn 2054 and 2068 into 1954 and 1968. But is there a more elegant and less error-prone method of parsing two-digit dates so that they get handled correctly in the parsing process itself?

**Update:** After @JoshuaUlrich pointed me to `strptime` I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508747/r-adding-century-to-year), which deals with an issue similar to mine, but using base R.

It seems like a nice addition to date handling in R would be some way to handle century selection cutoffs for two-digit dates within the date parsing functions.

Comment: Technically, the dates are being parsed correctly, since the documentation (`?strptime`) states that: "On input, values 00 to 68 are prefixed by 20 and 69 to 99 by 19 - that is the behaviour specified by the 2004 and 2008 POSIX standards".  `?parse_date` briefly tells you to see `?strptime` for the formats.

Comment: I should have been more precise. I didn't mean to imply that `lubridate` has a bug, but merely that because of the ambiguity of two-digit years, the package's natural behavior results in incorrect four-digit years ("incorrect" in the sense of "not the desired result") under some relatively common situations. I was hoping that there was some way within `lubridate` to specify a "switch" or "cutoff" value that will give the desired century for given ranges of two-digit dates.

Comment: Suggest you submit a feature request to lubridate's github page.

Comment: As suggested by Spacedman, I've added a feature request to @Hadley's github page.

Comment: Note that this is no longer lubridate's behavior. For your example, the output is now `[1] "2054-01-02 UTC" "2068-01-02 UTC" "2069-01-02 UTC" "2099-01-02 UTC" "2004-01-02 UTC"`.

Comment: How can force lubridate to use a different cutoff year instead of 1969?

Comment: @skan, `parse_date_time2` has a cutoff_2000 option. Here you can specify a different cutoff year.

Comment: @phiver's tip is great. Unfortunately, one can't use multiple date formats in the  `parse_date_time`'s  `orders` argument. So (e.g.) can't match both two and four digit years with `c("dmY", "dmy")`. (Workaround would be to copy date column first and perform operation twice, but it's clumsy)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Here is a function that allows you to do this:

```
library(lubridate)
x <- mdy(c("1/2/54","1/2/68","1/2/69","1/2/99","1/2/04"))


foo <- function(x, year=1968){
  m <- year(x) %% 100
  year(x) <- ifelse(m > year %% 100, 1900+m, 2000+m)
  x
}
```

Try it out:

```
x
[1] "2054-01-02 UTC" "2068-01-02 UTC" "1969-01-02 UTC" "1999-01-02 UTC"
[5] "2004-01-02 UTC"

foo(x)
[1] "2054-01-02 UTC" "2068-01-02 UTC" "1969-01-02 UTC" "1999-01-02 UTC"
[5] "2004-01-02 UTC"

foo(x, 1950)
[1] "1954-01-02 UTC" "1968-01-02 UTC" "1969-01-02 UTC" "1999-01-02 UTC"
[5] "2004-01-02 UTC"
```

---

The bit of magic here is to use the modulus operator `%%` to return the fraction part of a division.  So `1968 %% 100` yields 68.

Comment: Nice! Just noticed your answer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

I just experienced this exact same bug / feature.

I ended up writing the following two quick functions to help convert from excel-type dates (which is where i get this most) to something R can use.

There's nothing wrong with the accepted answer -- it's just that i prefer not to load up on packages too much.

First, a helper to split and replace the years ...

```
year1900 <- function(dd_y, yrFlip = 50)
{
    dd_y <- as.numeric(dd_y)
    dd_y[dd_y > yrFlip] <- dd_y[dd_y > yrFlip] + 1900
    dd_y[dd_y < yrFlip] <- dd_y[dd_y < yrFlip] + 2000
    return(dd_y)
}
```

which is used by a function that 'fixes' your excel dates, depending on type:

```
XLdate <- function(Xd, type = 'b-Y')
{
    switch(type,
        'b-Y' = as.Date(paste0(substr(Xd, 5, 9), "-", substr(Xd, 1, 3), "-01"), format = "%Y-%b-%d"),
        'b-y' = as.Date(paste0(year1900(substr(Xd, 5, 6)), "-", substr(Xd, 1, 3), "-01"), 
                        format = "%Y-%b-%d"),
        'Y-b' = as.Date(paste0(substr(Xd, 1, 3), "-", substr(Xd, 5, 9), "-01"), format =     "%Y-%b-%d")
        )
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be:

```
xxx <- c("01-Jan-54","01-Feb-68","01-Aug-69","01-May-99","01-Jun-04", "
       31-Dec-68","01-Jan-69", "31-Dec-99")
```

.

```
dmy(paste0(sub("\\d\\d$","",xxx) , ifelse( (tt <- 
   sub("\\d\\d-\\D\\D\\D-","",xxx)  ) > 20 ,paste0("19",tt),paste0("20",tt))))
```

Though no solution is elegant nor short.
I think it would be better if lubridate just added an option to specify the cutoff date.