# R incorrect value of date function

Tags: r, date

I'm trying to use as.Date in R.

I'm using the command:

```
as.Date("65-05-14", "%y-%m-%d")
```

I get:

```
"2065-05-14"
```

Is there any way to get it show 1965 instead? Or do I need to recode everything into long format -- eg add 1900 as a numeric?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12323693/is-there-a-more-elegant-way-to-convert-two-digit-years-to-four-digit-years-with

Comment: try `format(as.Date("65-05-14", "%y-%m-%d"), "19%y-%m-%d")`

Comment: @KFB, I'm presuming this came from http://stackoverflow.com/q/9508747/1270695.... Should this be closed as a duplicate of one of these questions?

Comment: @KFB: hm -- would that only work for the 90's? Say instead I head 114 (corresponding to 2014). I think yours might crash.

Comment: Try maybe using `POSIXlt` class, something like `Date <- as.POSIXlt(as.Date("65-05-14", "%y-%m-%d")) ; Date$year <- Date$year - 100L`. Should also work on a whole vector.

Comment: @user1357015, Seems the link provided by Ananda has the answer to your question.  Have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't see this simple solution in the linked questions, so I'm adding it here too.

In base R you can simply use `as.POSIXlt` class which provides `year` attribute. You can then simply reduce 100 years.

Lets say this is your dates vector

```
(Date <- c("65-05-14", "15-05-14", "25-05-14", "34-05-14"))
## [1] "65-05-14" "15-05-14" "25-05-14" "34-05-14"
```

You can simply do

```
Date <- as.POSIXlt(Date, format = "%y-%m-%d")
Date$year <- Date$year - 100L
Date # Alternatively, you could also do `as.Date(Date)`
## [1] "1965-05-14 IDT" "1915-05-14 IDT" "1925-05-14 IDT" "1934-05-14 IDT"
```