# R Lubridate Returns Unwanted Century When Given Two Digit Year

Tags: r, date, datetime, lubridate

In **R**, I have a vector of strings representing dates in two different formats:

1. "month/day/year"
2. "month day, year"

The first format has a two digit year so my vector looks something like this:

```
c("3/18/75", "March 10, 1994", "10/1/80", "June 15, 1979",...)
```

I want to put the dates in the vector in a standard format. This should be easy with the `mdy` function from the `lubridate` package, except when I pass it the first format, it returns an unwanted century.

`mdy("3/18/75")` returns `"2075-03-18 UTC"`

**Does anyone know how it can return the date in the 20th century? That is "1975-03-18 UTC"**. Any other solution of how to standardize the dates will be greatly appreciated as well.

I am running version lubridate_1.3.3 if that matters.

Comment: Interesting.  `as.Date("3/18/75", "%m/%d/%y")` returns the correct century.  The lubridate `origin` is the standard 1970 origin as well.  Weird.

Comment: Here is a brilliant reply to this problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12957909/7941188

Comment: This is not an issue running lubridate v  1.7.1

Comment: Filed an issue: https://github.com/tidyverse/lubridate/issues/795

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Lubridate v1.7.1 does not have this issue.

Comment: Not true, I can reproduce it in any 1.7.* version.

Answer (score 3):

You could do it like this:

```
some_dates <- c("3/18/75", "March 10, 1994", "10/1/80", "June 15, 1979")
dates <- mdy(some_dates)
future_dates <- year(dates) > year(Sys.Date())
year(dates[future_dates]) <- year(dates[future_dates]) - 100
```

Maybe a better approach would be to remove the ambiguity from your date strings though -- otherwise your code will be wrong when 2075 rolls around ;)

```
library(stringr)
some_dates <- c('3/18/75', '01/09/53')
str_replace(some_dates, '[0-9]+$', '19\\0')
```

Or if the two date strings are mixed:

```
some_dates <- c("3/18/75", "March 10, 1994", "10/1/80", "June 15, 1979")
str_replace(some_dates, '/([0-9]{2}$)', '/19\\1')
```

Answer (score 2):

lubridate v1.7.4 does.  Looking at a 2068 as we speak

Answer (score 0):

You can use a postprocessing function to adjust the century threshold:

```
library(lubridate)
dates <- c("3/18/75", "March 10, 1994", "10/1/80", "June 15, 1979", "10/19/15")

adjustCentury <- function(d, threshold=1930){
  y <- year(d) %% 100
  if(y > threshold %% 100) year(d) <- 1900 + y
  d
}

lapply(lapply(dates, mdy), adjustCentury)
```

results in:

```
[[1]]
[1] "1975-03-18 UTC"

[[2]]
[1] "1994-03-10 UTC"

[[3]]
[1] "1980-10-01 UTC"

[[4]]
[1] "1979-06-15 UTC"

[[5]]
[1] "2015-10-19 UTC"
```