# Using the "format" argument in as.Date()

Tags: r, as.date

I'm trying to convert "07,29,30" into a Date format using as.Date() in R.

(Note that the format of the string is "mm,dd,yy", being July 29, 1930)

So I used the following code:

```
as.Date("07,29,30", format = "%m,%d,%y")
```

But the year that I get returned is 2030, not 1930.
How can I tell R to convert the value to the date a century before?

Comment: look at this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12323693/is-there-a-more-elegant-way-to-convert-two-digit-years-to-four-digit-years-with

Comment: I'm having flashbacks to the Y2K days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As year values between 00 and 68 are coded as 20 for century.
From `strptime` documentation, it seems following is the reason for this.

> "Year without century (00–99). On input, values 00 to 68 are prefixed
>   by 20 and 69 to 99 by 19 – that is the behaviour specified by the 2004
>   and 2008 POSIX standards, but they do also say ‘it is expected that in
>   a future version the default century inferred from a 2-digit year will
>   change’."

You can use the below code to recode it.

```
d <- as.Date("07,29,30", format = "%m,%d,%y")

> as.Date(ifelse(d > today(), format(d, "19%y-%m-%d"), format(d)))
[1] "1930-07-29"
```

Answer (score 2):

I'll put in anyways:

```
# use this library
library(lubridate)

# convert to the format (your way or you acn use lubridate)
dateconvert <- as.Date("07,29,30", format = "%m,%d,%y") 

# get the year
inputYear <- year(dateconvert)

# convert the year
year(dateconvert) <- ifelse(inputYear > 2000, 1900 + (inputYear %% 100), inputYear)
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve this issue use `strtotime()` and `date()`:

```
$originalDate = "2010-03-21";
$newDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($originalDate));
```

Comment: do you mean strptime()?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:
format(as.Date("07,29,30", format = "%m,%d,%y"), "19%y-%m-%d")