# Character 2 digit year conversion to year only

Tags: r, date, character, 2-digit-year

Using R

Got large clinical health data set to play with, but dates are weird

Most problematic is `2digityear/halfyear`, as in `98/2`, meaning at some point in `1998` after `July 1`

I have split the column up into 2 character columns, e.g. `98` and `2` but now need to convert the `2` digit year character string into an actual year.

I tried `as.Date(data$variable,format="%Y")` but not only did I get a conversion to `0098` as the year rather than `1998`, I also got todays month and year arbitrarily added (the actual data has no month or day).

as in `0098-06-11`

How do I get just 1998 instead?

Comment: Are they all in the 90s(20th century)?

Comment: no, unfortunately it's got 2000s as well

Comment: Alright, so how does one know which belongs to which? Like how do you differentiate between 1901 and 2001 for instance?

Comment: testing for the disease was not available until the 1980s.

Comment: This could be relevant [Is there a more elegant way to convert two-digit years to four-digit years with lubridate?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12323693/5193830)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not elegant. But using combination of lubridate and as.Date you can get that.

```
library(lubridate)
data <- data.frame(variable = c(95, 96, 97,98,99), date=c(1,2,3,4,5))
data$variableUpdated <- year(as.Date(as.character(data$variable), format="%y"))
```

and only with base R

```
data$variableUpdated <- format(as.Date(as.character(data$variable), format="%y"),"%Y")
```

Comment: I apologize I have only been using R for a couple of weeks.  Can you explain how to assign that to the variable?  Ive been doing this by code like:    data$variableUpdated <- as.Date(data$variable,format="%Y").  Do I slip the years list in the middle?   data$variableUpdated <- format(as.Date(data$variable,, years, format ("%y")),"%Y"))

Comment: I tried the code I wrote above and it made mostly NAs and replaced a few dates with today's date (which doesn't exist in the data set).  What did I do wrong?

Comment: yes, you are right. Add as.character to convert it to string. `data$variableUpdated <- format(as.Date(as.character(data$variable), format ("%y")),"%Y")`