# Can't convert yymmdd to mmddyy

Tags: r, lubridate

Here mydata

```
ga=structure(list(Date = c(190410L, 190410L, 190410L, 190410L, 190410L
), open = c(162.4, 162.57, 162.94, 162.87, 162.96), high = c(162.57, 
162.94, 162.95, 163, 163.11), low = c(162.12, 162.51, 162.83, 
162.83, 162.95), close = c(162.57, 162.94, 162.9, 162.95, 162.95
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

I use `mdy` function from `lubridate`

```
ga$Date=mdy(ga$Date)
```

So I get only `NA`.
How can i get such output format(mm.dd.yy)

```
    Date        open   high    low  close
1   04.10.2019 162.40 162.57 162.12 162.57
2   04.10.2019 162.57 162.94 162.51 162.94
3   04.10.2019 162.94 162.95 162.83 162.90
4   04.10.2019162.87 163.00 162.83 162.95
5   04.10.2019 162.96 163.11 162.95 162.95
```

Comment: Do you need this? `lubridate::ymd(ga$Date)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use base R to get output in required format

```
ga$Date <- format(as.Date(as.character(ga$Date), "%y%m%d"), "%m.%d.%Y")

ga
#        Date   open   high    low  close
#1 04.10.2019 162.40 162.57 162.12 162.57
#2 04.10.2019 162.57 162.94 162.51 162.94
#3 04.10.2019 162.94 162.95 162.83 162.90
#4 04.10.2019 162.87 163.00 162.83 162.95
#5 04.10.2019 162.96 163.11 162.95 162.95
```

Comment: may i ask you, how to aggaregate variable (open   high    low  close) by date by sum?

Comment: @G-spot `aggregate` by group? `aggregate(.~Date, ga, sum)`.

Answer (score 3):

We can use:

```
strftime(lubridate::ymd(ga$Date),"%m %d %Y")
[1] "04 10 2019" "04 10 2019" "04 10 2019" "04 10 2019" "04 10 2019"
```

The above will return a character representation of the date, if you want to keep as date(I find the display somewhat misleading), you could use:

```
lubridate::mdy(strftime(lubridate::ymd(ga$Date),"%m %d %y"))
[1] "2019-04-10" "2019-04-10" "2019-04-10" "2019-04-10" "2019-04-10"
```

Perhaps `mdy` defaults to this kind of representation as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37736131/lubridate-mdy-function).

Answer (score 3):

We can use `anydate` from `anytime`

```
library(anytime)
format(anydate(as.character(ga$Date)), "%m.%d.%Y")
#[1] "04.10.2019" "04.10.2019" "04.10.2019" "04.10.2019" "04.10.2019"
```

---

If we want to convert a date time format

```
str1 <- "190410;100000"
format(as.POSIXct(str1, format= "%y%m%d;%H%M%S"), "%m.%d.%Y %H:%M")
#[1] "04.10.2019 10:00"
```