# Inserting prefix of 19 into a string date

Tags: r, regex, date

I have a vector of birth dates as character strings formatted "10-Feb-85".

When I use the `as.Date()` function in `R` it assumes the two digit year is after 2000 (none of these birth dates are after the year 2000).

example:
`as.Date(x = "10-Feb-52", format = "%d-%b-%y")`

returns: `2052-02-10`

I'm not proficient in regular expressions but 
I think that this is an occasion for a regular expression to insert a "19" after the second "-" or before the last two digits.

I've found a regex that counts forward three characters and inserts a letter:

`gsub(pattern = "^(.{3})(.*)$", replacement = "\\1d\\2", x = "abcefg")`

But I'm not sure how to count two from the end.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: from `?strptime` : On input, values 00 to 68 are prefixed by 20 and 69 to 99 by 19 – that is the behaviour specified by the 2004 and 2008 POSIX standards, but they do also say ‘it is expected that in a future version the default century inferred from a 2-digit year will change’.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew , I am familiar enough with the data. There might be a few from the 1800's but I doubt it.

Comment: You may try the `lubridate`: `lubridate::dmy(c("10-Feb-85", "10-Feb-15"))
[1] "1985-02-10" "2015-02-10"`

Comment: @UweBlock: That way you add `19` or `20`,  and they are added at the beginning, while the task is to add only `19` at the last 2 digits that are after the second hyphen.

Comment: Also, the [`cron` solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508747/add-correct-century-to-dates-with-year-provided-as-year-without-century-y) suggested as a dupe source inserts either `20` or `19`, which is not what is expected here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> insert a "19" after the second "-" or before the last two digits.

Before the last two digits:

```
gsub(pattern = "-(\\d{2})$", replacement = "-19\\1", x = "10-Feb-52")
```

See the [R demo](http://ideone.com/ACK91J). Here, `-` is matched first, then 2 digits (`(\\d{2})`) - that are at the end of string (`$`) - are matched and captured into Group 1.

After the second `-`:

```
gsub(pattern = "^((?:[^-]*-){2})", replacement = "\\119", x = "10-Feb-52")
```

See [another demo](http://ideone.com/9jKQK3). Here, 2 sequences (`{2}`) of 0+ chars other than `-` (`[^-]*`) are matched from the start of the string (`^`) and captured into group 1. The replacement contains a backreference that restores the captured text in the replacement result.

Comment: What about "10-Feb-15"? Shouldn't this become 2015-02-10?

Comment: @UweBlock: Ask OP, acc. to the current question, it should not.