# as.Date with two-digit years

Tags: r, date, as.date

If I convert the date `10.10.61` (DD.MM.YY) with `as.Date(date, format="%d.%m.%y")` for some reason it converts it into ***2061***-10-10.

Is there an elegant way to correct for this or do I have to do it manually by slicing the string and adding "19" in front?

I've also tried the *zoo* package which brings up the same (wrong) result.

Comment: The reason is found in `?strptime`: _"Year without century (00–99). On input, values 00 to 68 are prefixed by 20 and 69 to 99 by 19 – that is the behaviour specified by the 2004 and 2008 POSIX standards"_

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
x = format(as.Date("10.10.61", "%d.%m.%y"), "19%y-%m-%d")
x = as.Date(x)
x
class(x)
```

Answer (score 5):

Note that a single `sub` will slice the string and prepend the year with 19 so it is not so onerous:

```
as.Date(sub("(..)$", "19\\1", date), "%d.%m.%Y")
## [1] "1961-10-10"
```

**chron** Alternately, the chron package defaults to a cutoff of 30 so it will use 1961 by default:

```
library(chron)
as.Date(dates(date, format = "d.m.y"))
## [1] "1961-10-10"
```

In chron the year expansion rule is defined by the `"chron.year.expand"` option which by default is set to the `year.expand` function and that function's default `cut.off` is 30.  See this SO post for more info:
[Add correct century to dates with year provided as "Year without century", %y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508747/add-correct-century-to-dates-with-)

Answer (score 0):

If all your dates in 1900s, then you can use this solution:

```
library(magrittr)
your_date = '10.10.61'
as.Date(your_date,format="%d.%m.%y") %>% format("19%y%m%d") %>% as.Date("%Y%m%d")
```

Answer (score 0):

If all your dates are in the past, but some are in the 2000s (such as with birthdates), you can use this solution:

```
origDates = c('10.10.61','10.10.01')

badDates = as.Date(origDates,'%d.%m.%y')
badDates
## [1] "2061-10-10" "2001-10-10"

goodDates = ifelse(badDates > Sys.Date(),
                   format(badDates,'19%y-%m-%d'),
                   format(badDates,'%Y-%m-%d'))
newDates = as.Date(goodDates)
newDates
## [1] "1961-10-10" "2001-10-10"
```