# `as.Date()` identifies years in short form(say 01/10/68) as `2068-10-01` instead of `1968-10-01`, how to fix it?

Tags: r, date, data-science, data-analysis, as.date

I have a csv dataset that has date of births stored as characters in the format - `01-06-68`(`"%d-%m-%y"`). I tried to convert the dates to `Date` objects using `as.Date()` but it identifies the year as `2068` when in fact the year is `1968`. I understand `Date` starts from `1970-01-01` in R, is there an easy fix to this?

I am using the `lubridate` package to find the age.
Some age were negative due to the wrongly identified year.

```
elapsed <- train$Date.of.Birth %--% Sys.Date()
train$age <- floor(as.duration(elapsed) / dyears(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try

```
format(as.Date(date,format="%d-%m-%y"), "19%y-%m-%d")
```

You probably need to use %Y anyway bite the bullet and create a new df with complete years else your are screwed when 19xx transitions to 20xx.

Good Luck.

Comment: Thank you, but you were close, the answer for (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508747/add-correct-century-to-dates-with-year-provided-as-year-without-century-y) had the following solution : `d <- as.Date(xx, "%d%b%y")`
`as.Date(ifelse(d > "2012-12-31", format(d, "19%y-%m-%d"), format(d)))`